# Mockito change the arguments passed to a mock

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4

i have a class which reads and writes values from/to a byte-buffer.

My write method looks like this:

```
public void write(final ByteBuffer buffer) {
    buffer.putInt(messageLength);
    buffer.putShort(version);
    foo.write(buffer);
    buffer.putInt(checkSum);
    ...
}
```

Now i want to write a Unit test for this method and i want the foo-object to be mocked (which is pretty easy).
But is it possible that the mocked-foo instance actually does something to the buffer?

In this case when().thenReturn() doesn't help me since the return value is not used.

Comment: You can use an Answer when you want a mock to have a side effect.

Comment: You talk about the mocking void method I think.     doNothing().when(foo).write(buffer);

Comment: But doing nothing is not what i want. I want to manipulate the byte buffer.